# How can I copy all files from all subfolders of a folder to another folder in Python?

Tags: python

How to copy all files from some folders to another folder? All files are *png*.

Comment: It may be prudent to visit one of those links above, give it a go and if you stumble upon any problems, paste what you've got into your question. Otherwise you'll find this closed as a duplicate or too broad a question

Comment: @dot.Py, inside the folders, there are some subfolders. I want to copy all png files from all folders and subfolders.

Comment: @AmnKh maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196512/how-to-copy-all-files-from-a-folder-including-sub-folder-while-not-copying-the

Comment: @dot.Py, Thank you. It works for me.