# Using os.walk with passing a variable

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to learn passing variables by making a small script to copy all files from an input directory path and copy them to another folder.

I have one function which verifies the input path the user provides and then I want this passed to my move_files function as a variable.

This is the code of what I am trying to attempt:

```
def verification():
    verify_path = input()
    if verify_path[0] == "\"" and verify_path[-1] != '"':
        verify_path = verify_path[1:]
        pass
    elif verify_path[:-1] == "\"" and verify_path[0] != '"':
        verify_path = verify_path[:-1]
        pass
    elif verify_path[0] == '"' and verify_path[-1] == '"':
        verify_path = verify_path[1:-1]
        pass
    else:
        pass
    print ('Your path is: ' + (verify_path) + '\nIs this okay? If so, hit the y key. If this is not okay hit the n key to change to path or x to exit')
    char = bytes.decode(msvcrt.getch(), encoding="utf-8")
    if char.upper() == 'Y':
        pass
    elif char.upper() != 'Y':
        print ("Please copy and paste in a new path")
        verify_path = input()
    elif char.upper() != 'x':
        exit()
    else:
        pass
    return verify_path

def move_files(original_path):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(original_path):
        for file in files:
            try:
                new_path = os.mkdir(os.path.join(cwd,'Copy Folder'))
            except FileExistsError:
                continue
        path_file = os.path.join(root, dirs, file)
        print(path_file)
        shutil.copy2(path_file,new_path)


def main():
    move_files(original_path =verification())

main()
```

I was initially encountering an error that 'dirs' was an unused variable so I included it in my path_file variable.

Then I encountered another error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment'

[I used this answer as a basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196512/how-to-copy-all-files-from-a-folder-including-sub-folder-while-not-copying-the/23197213) for copying the files
[I followed this guide](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/global_&_return.html) to pass variables but am having trouble

Any direction would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `file` variable in `path_file = os.path.join(root, dirs, file)` 
 line outside of `for` loop which makes python throw the error `'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment'`

Also, you're trying to make `'Copy Folder'` multiple times in `for` loop. I think you should do it just once outside of the for loop, before copying the files.

Correction in your code:

```py
def move_files(original_path):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    try:
        new_path = os.mkdir(os.path.join(cwd,'Copy Folder'))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(original_path):
        for file in files:
             path_file = os.path.join(root, file)
             print(path_file)
             shutil.copy2(path_file,new_path)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay Dabas , Looks the above will work but an error's occuring with the continue not being inside the loop? Pretty strange when, with the same indenting in the for block its okay but once its taken outside of the for block I'm getting that error

Comment: Sorry, it should be `pass` and not `continue` outside of the loop. I updated the answer

Comment: Yep, got it so all good. I found though that I had to create a variable outside the def move_files function, for my 'Copy Folder' otherwise I was stil getting the error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_path' referenced before assignment'.